# how to add new menu item with observer in magento2?

Tags: magento2

how to add new menu item with observer in magento2?

I have define event in config.xml in my module as below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after">
        <observer name="namespacetest_page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after" instance="Namespace\Test\Observer\AddMenu"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and below observer file contain code

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\Test\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class AddMenu implements ObserverInterface
{


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $event    = $observer->getEvent();
       // function not called when event occur


    }

}
```

what I am doing wrong here? Please help me in figure out the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have define event in wrong file name. i.e. **config.xml**

It should be **events.xml** in directory

```
[magentoroot]/app/code/Namespace/Test/etc/frontend/events.xml
```